# node.js express rendering inside included js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Lets say I have a simple view

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>something</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= param %>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

And here's `myscript.js`

```
$(function() {
  var p = <%= param %>
}
```

Can I make express rendering engine (in this case `ejs`) render inside `myscript.js` ?

Comment: Any reason you can't use static javascript files and dynamic JSON?

Comment: @giaour can you elaborate on this a little ?

Comment: Not passing your JavaScript through the rendering engine will speed up your page, both because view rendering consumes resources and because browsers aggressively cache static files. If the only thing that changes in your javascript files is the value of `param`, then you can feed it into your page in other ways -- either by having your script make AJAX requests that get handled by Express or by interpolating them into an inline script tag on whatever page uses your script.

Comment: thanks for that, makes sense. Although I wouldn't go as far as making an AJAX call, it has i/o overhead as well probably bigger than the rendering but you're probably right about making the script inline...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe express will touch your static files. You could make this a view that gets rendered and served from a route, as in:

```
app.get('/js/myscript.js', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('myscript'); 
});
```

With regex routes, you could do this with anything ending in `.js`. (Before anyone downvotes, note that I said **could**, not **should**.)

You probably would be better off with static javascript being served to the browser that uses JSON data served from Express, though.

Comment: +1 for this. "You probably would be better off with static javascript being served to the browser that uses JSON data served from Express, though"

Comment: how could I do it with non static js?